# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) in swift 2

Tags: swift2

My app is working fine when it run in simulator but when I connect it to device, it is giving an following error

ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm using Xcode 7.1 and an iPhone with iOS 8.3

Comment: So you don't have an arm-compatible version of the `AFNetworking` library, then?

Comment: @trojanfoe Since that is the correct answer, why not make it an answer :-)

Comment: @JeremyP It won't be that simple.  Cocoapods will be involved or something similar. Better to just comment and run :)

Comment: hii @trojanfoe, I am new in ios development,it is my first project. So I am not aware of arm-compatible version so plz suggest me which version of AFNetworking have to use,so that my issue will solve. I am using pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6.3' version